# UITableView with Multiple Sections using Realm and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

Ok, so I found a lot of information regarding UITableView and multiple sections, however, they are always with strings, arrays, static data, Obj-C or something else with which I am unable to translate to my situation, mainly because I am completely new to developing apps. Any help is greatly appreciated since it has been a little over a month that I have been trying different approaches without success.

So I have multiple Dog objects with the following properties:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var race = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    dynamic var owner = ""
    dynamic var dogID = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "dogID"
    }
}
```

And in my ViewController file I have the following code (I removed the irrelevant lines):

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var dogResults : Results<Dog>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dogResults = realm.objects(Dog.self)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dogResults!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let dog = self.dogResults![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = dog.name
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        // ?
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // ?
}
```

I would like to organize the sections by the "race" property from the Dog object, however I am having a very difficult time achieving this.

I saw a few examples where they use the "if" statement for the sections, I have tried that and was not able to get the proper results, however, I would like the cleaner approach I have seen in some other examples, using:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data[section].count
}
```

I have made various attempts, but being a Realm DB and swift I am having problems following most of the examples.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's some sample code that does exactly what you're looking for:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var race = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    dynamic var owner = ""
    dynamic var dogID = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "dogID"
    }

    convenience init(name: String, race: String, dogID: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.race = race
        self.dogID = dogID
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let items = try! Realm().objects(Dog.self).sorted(["race", "name"])
    var sectionNames: [String] {
        return Set(items.valueForKeyPath("race") as! [String]).sort()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let realm = try! Realm()
        if realm.isEmpty {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Bailey", race: "Golden Retrievers", dogID: "0"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Bella", race: "German Shepherds", dogID: "1"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Max", race: "Bulldogs", dogID: "2"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Lucy", race: "Yorkshire Terriers", dogID: "3"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Charlie", race: "Bulldogs", dogID: "4"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Molly", race: "German Shepherds", dogID: "5"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Buddy", race: "German Shepherds", dogID: "6"))
                realm.add(Dog(name: "Daisy", race: "Siberian Huskies", dogID: "7"))
            }
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionNames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionNames[section]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.filter("race == %@", sectionNames[section]).count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items.filter("race == %@", sectionNames[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you jpsim! Worked like a charm!

Comment: This worked beautifully for me as well. Thank you so much! Consistently impressed with the Realm support I find in your documentation and here on SO.

Comment: @jpsim is it possible to combine this with the realm collection notifications? The example in the realm docs show how to update a table view with a single section based on the notifications only... thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but tricky and I don't have any sample code to share. If you find an elegant way to do it, please share.

Comment: @MikePollard Yes it it possible. We have set collection notifications for different sections but in our case we had to display 3 items in one section.

Comment: @jpsim Thanks for elegant solution

Comment: Great solution, but have 181 sections so it take time.  And on viewdidload "numberOfRowsInSection" are called for all section(event if not visible). (probably to calculate the scroll size).  Any suggestions?

Comment: You could help build out a more efficient built-in way to group results in Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3384

Comment: Hi.  @jpsim Any sample of group results?

Comment: @jpsim was hoping this would be my solution, but it appears Realm no longer has the valueForKeyPath as something we can call on the Results object.  Is there documentation on how this might be accomplished now?