# Creating an indexed tableview using Realm in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have a list of contacts stored in a realm database, and now I want display the names of the contacts in a table view. As a list this works fine and can be sorted in ascending order of names ok. I'm struggling with grouping these names for each letter in an index list. My code is filling each section with the same information.

My code looks like this:

```
    var contacts: Results<ContactItem>!
var contactIndexTitles = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tblContacts: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupUI()
    let contactIndex = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
    contactIndexTitles = contactIndex.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    self.reloadTheTable()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    reloadTheTable()
}


func setupUI() {
    tblContacts.delegate = self
    tblContacts.dataSource = self
}

func reloadTheTable() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        contacts = realm.objects(ContactItem).sorted("Name", ascending: true)
        tblContacts.reloadData()
        print("reload tbl \(contacts)")

    } catch {

    }
}

//willDisplayCell forRowAtIndexPath
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

//numberOfSectionsInTableView
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contactIndexTitles.count
}

//sectionForSectionIndexTitle
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int{

    return index
}

//titleForHeaderInSection
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

    return self.contactIndexTitles[section] as String
}

//numberOfRowsInSection
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return contacts.count
}

//sectionIndexTitlesForTableView
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return contactIndexTitles as [String]
}

//cellForRowAtIndexPath
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let identifer: String = "myCell"
    var cell = tblContacts.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifer)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifer)
    }

    let contactinfo = contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = contactinfo.Name
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = contactinfo.KeyNumber
    return cell!
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions on how to filter the realm database and populate the sections correctly?

EDIT

So I've amended the code using the first link and the sample given and it's displaying ok.

[image: current screenshot]

TableViewController code:

```
var contacts: Results<ContactItem>!
```

var contactIndexTitles = String

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblcontacts: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupUI()
    self.reloadTheTable()
    let contactIndex = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
    contactIndexTitles = contactIndex.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    //print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    reloadTheTable()
}

func setupUI() {

    tblcontacts.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

func reloadTheTable() {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        contacts = realm.objects(ContactItem.self).sorted("Name")
        tblcontacts.reloadData()
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contactIndexTitles.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return contactIndexTitles[section]
}

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return contactIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contacts.filter("Name BEGINSWITH %@", contactIndexTitles[section]).count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tblcontacts.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = contacts.filter("Name BEGINSWITH %@", contactIndexTitles[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row].Name
    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let contact : ContactItem = contacts[indexPath.row]  //, contactIndexTitles[indexPath.section])
    print(contact)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("addContact", sender: contact)
    print("Selected row at \(indexPath.row)")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
if(segue.identifier == "addContact")
    {
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddEntryViewController
        viewController.contact = sender as! ContactItem

    }
}
```

}

Now I have one more problem and thats the segue to the next controller. I can't seem to get the code correct to able to go to the correct row in the correct section. 
How can I select the correct row from the correct section?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38797693/373262 for an example of a grouped tableview.

Comment: I've been looking at the example suggested and can see how its done using hard coded info but not using an array for the section and a results list for the objects. Either I'm missing something simple or I'm way off the mark, and not being a programmer it's probably the later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample derived from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797693/373262 for your models and specifying a hardcoded array of section titles as your comment above requested:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ContactItem: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var keyNumber = ""

    convenience init(name: String, keyNumber: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.keyNumber = keyNumber
    }
}

let alphabet = (UnicodeScalar("A").value...UnicodeScalar("Z").value).flatMap(UnicodeScalar.init)

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let items = try! Realm().objects(ContactItem.self).sorted(byProperty: "name")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let realm = try! Realm()
        if realm.isEmpty {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Bailey", keyNumber: "0"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Bella", keyNumber: "1"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Max", keyNumber:"2"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Lucy", keyNumber: "3"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Charlie", keyNumber:"4"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Molly", keyNumber: "5"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Buddy", keyNumber: "6"))
                realm.add(ContactItem(name: "Daisy", keyNumber: "7"))
            }
        }
    }

    func items(forSection section: Int) -> Results<ContactItem> {
        return items.filter("name BEGINSWITH %@", alphabet[section].description)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return alphabet.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return alphabet[section].description
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items(forSection: section).count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let contactinfo = items(forSection: indexPath.section)[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = contactinfo.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contactinfo.keyNumber
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's the end result:

[image: screenshot]

And a link to the Xcode project: https://static.realm.io/debug/RealmContacts.tgz

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't do what I expected though. The only thing displayed on the simulator was "A". Sorry not sure how to add a screenshot to this comment.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of what this code produces, as well as a link to the full Xcode project.

Comment: I've looked at the project thank you. I can't run it though without making changes. I'm using xcode 7.3 swift 2.2. Modifying a couple bits to be able to run the code it just produces "A" on the simulator only. Thank you again for your help and patience.

Comment: Yeah i sort of guessed that with the error it came up with. I'm still playing around with it trying to sort it.  Guess it's gonna be a long learning process. Anymore ideas?

Comment: Why is it a long learning process? Xcode is available on the Mac App Store, and this project is entirely self-contained.

Comment: Learning process for me i meant.

Comment: I've added some adjustments to code in my edit that work but one more problem to overcome now.