# Realm Swift updating collectionView with sections

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, realm

I have a collectionView that I've just added sections to and I'm using RealmSwift. Before I added the sections, I was able to make changes to the data and see them updated/removed in my collectionView.

I followed the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Enums/RealmCollectionChange.html) to add a notification so that changes in my results object would trigger the UI changes; notice I made the appropriate changes for my collectionView.

```
func notificationSubscription(for outfits: Results<Outfit>) -> NotificationToken {
    return outfits.addNotificationBlock({ [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Outfit>>) in
        self?.updateUI(with: changes)
    })
}

func updateUI(with changes: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Outfit>>) {
    switch changes {
    case .initial(_):
        collectionView.reloadData()
    case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
            self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
        }, completion: { (completed: Bool) in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
        break
    case let .error(error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

It's clear to me that the problem in `updateUI(with: changes)` is that the IndexPaths are hardcoded to be at section 0. My app crashed due to this when I edited an item so I searched around and came across [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4186#issuecomment-261458292) issue on GitHub. Pawelkata (commentor) mentioned that a quick fix for the issue (now closed) was to call `collectionView.reloadData()` from within the `update` case of the switch statement.

```
func updateUI(with changes: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Outfit>>) {
    switch changes {
    case .initial(_):
        collectionView.reloadData()
    case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
        collectionView.reloadData()
        break
    case let .error(error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

While the quick fix works for modifications and insertions it fails in the case of deletion. This is because new data is added/modified elsewhere but deletions happen on the same viewController so the changes don't actually update the UI.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38797693/2892925) closely related stackoverflow question in which @jpsim answers someone's question about having multiple sections in a tableView. In the comments @MikePollard asks if it's possible to combine a tableView with multiple sections with the realm collection notifications. JPSim says it's tricky, but possible. Although I have a collectionView and not a tableView I am making the assumption that this is also possible.

What I've tried:

1. Since I needed to know the section the item came from, I created a variable to store the indexPath of the item that was selected. 
   `var indexPathForDeletion = IndexPath()`

   Which I then set in `didSelectItem`, and use in `updateUI(with: changes)`.

   ```
   func updateUI(with changes: RealmCollectionChange<Results<Outfit>>) {
       switch changes {
       case .initial(_):
           collectionView.reloadData()
       case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
           collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
               self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [self.indexPathForDeletion])
           }, completion: { (completed: Bool) in
               self.collectionView.reloadData()
           })
           break
       case let .error(error):
           print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
   }
   ```

   The app crashes with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 2.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

   I started with 2 items, I deleted 1 item, I should have 1 item left but it appears I still have 2. That's my interpretation of the error. Did I interpret that correctly? Why wouldn't the item be deleted?
2. I have a hash table to store the sections and it's array of results so I created a function to update the hash table and then reload the collectionView.

   ```
   func refreshData() {
       getOutfitsByCategory()
       collectionView.reloadData()
   }

   func getOutfitsByCategory() {
       for category in categories {
           outfitsByCategory[category] = outfits.filter("category = %@", category)
       }
   }
   ```

   This gives me a "better" result but there seems to be some weirdness. I am able to delete items *iff* they are at index 0, regardless of section. However, deleting item at index 0 will delete the entire section that it's in.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many sections your collection view has, it might be easier to simply set a separate notification block for each set of results for each section. This would entail maintaining a separate `Results` object for each section (and the subsequent notification token), so depending on how many sections you have, this solution could be somewhat complex.

Another consideration might be to try out [`RBQFetchedResultsController`](https://github.com/Roobiq/RBQFetchedResultsController). This was a controller built before change notifications became available in Realm (As a third party project by a Realm employee), so while it's not as 'native' as the main collection notification system, it can also account for table/collection view sections.

Comment: Thanks @TiM! I only have about a dozen sections. I realize now that I misunderstood your suggestion but it guided me to the solution I implemented, which was to set a separate notifications for each section. I then just updated my hash table and reloaded the collectionView.

Comment: @MaryMartinez How to do `separate notifications`