# Grouped UITableView and Realm Notifications

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I have a `UITableView` that has two sections. Each section displays the results of querying for a particular Realm object.

```
var contentRequests: Results<UESocketPostRequest>? {
   return try? CustomRealm.realm().objects(UESocketPostRequest.self).filter("completed = false AND content != nil").sorted(byKeyPath: "content.createdAt", ascending: false)
}

var mediaUploads: Results<UEMediaUploadRequest>? {
    return try? CustomRealm.realm().objects(UEMediaUploadRequest.self).filter("finished = false").sorted(byKeyPath: "media.content.createdAt", ascending: false)
}
```

My `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` conformance:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return self.contentRequests?.count ?? 0
    case 1:
        return self.mediaUploads?.count ?? 0
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UPLOADCELL") as? UEUploadCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        if let request = self.contentRequests?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.softBindSocketRequest(request)
        }
    case 1:
        if let request = self.mediaUploads?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.softBindMediaUploadRequest(request)
        }
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

I then set up `NotificationToken`'s for each of my realm results and update the table view like this:

```
func startContentToken() {
    self.contentToken = self.contentRequests?.observe({ [weak self] (changes) in
        switch changes {
        case .error:
            break
        case .initial:
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)
            self?.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        case .update(let content, deletions: let deletions, insertions: let insertions, modifications: let modifications):
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    })
}

func startMediaToken() {
    self.mediaToken = self.mediaUploads?.observe({ [weak self] (changes) in
        switch changes {
        case .error:
            break
        case .initial:
            let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 1)
            self?.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        case .update(let media, deletions: let deletions, insertions: let insertions, modifications: let modifications):
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 1) }),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 1)}),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 1) }),
                                       with: .automatic)
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    })
}
```

I frequently get crashes because of a `UITableView` inconsistency exception encapsulated by this log message or something similar:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Am I doing something wrong or is Realm not designed for use with grouped `UITableView`'s in this way?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is maintain a manual count for each section. Update the count when you receive insertions or deletions in the realm notification block. Return the count in `numberOfRowsInSection`. More info here: [Updating UITableView with multiple sections from RLMResults.Observe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431313/updating-uitableview-with-multiple-sections-from-rlmresults-observe/59131236#59131236)