# Realm results object with incorrect results (iOS, Swift)

Tags: swift, realm, xcode11

I am having issues getting Realm's result object to be accessed correctly using UITableView's cellForRowAt.

Here's the setup:

UITableViewController is divided into sections based on the Objects's category (a string defined in the object).

UITableViewController has a segue to a UIViewController which takes form input.  That view controller writes to Realm and then makes a call back via delegation to refresh the table view data.

When that screen dismisses and returns to the UITableViewController, as I try to add the row via category, I am getting empty objects.  However, when I use a for loop within cellForRowAt, I can access the data.

Here is what I'm running in this section:

```
func loadItems() {
        itemsList = try! Realm().objects(Items.self).filter("list_id = \(list_id)").sorted(byKeyPath: "item_category")
        tableView.reloadData()

    }    

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemListCell", for: indexPath)
        let categoryName = categories.categories[indexPath.section]

        let currItem = itemsList[indexPath.row]

        if currItem.item_category == categoryName {
            cell.textLabel!.text = currItem.item_name
        }

        return cell
    }
```

It seems to be evaluating category correctly and stepping into that block, but the object's item_name and item_category is null.  Here is a screenshot of the debugger inside the if statement:

[Debugger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1IZm.png)

Is there something I need to change with how I'm using the object, pulling data, etc, to get the data correct in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here:  [UITableView with Multiple Sections using Realm and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728938/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-using-realm-and-swift)

This is the change I made to cellForRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemListCell", for: indexPath)

        let currItem = itemsList.filter("item_category = '\(categories[indexPath.section])'")[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = currItem.item_name

        return cell
    }
```

The issue I was having was I was constantly pulling the first position results object and not the first position within a section.  I needed to narrow down to my section and then pull the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to do with your filters predicate. Try changing

```
itemsList = try! Realm().objects(Items.self).filter("list_id = \(list_id)").sorted(byKeyPath: "item_category"
```

to this

```
itemsList = try! Realm().objects(Items.self).filter("list_id = '\(list_id)'").sorted(byKeyPath: "item_category"
```

Add single quotations around '(list_id)'.

[Realm Filtering](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering)

Comment: Actually, found the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728938/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-using-realm-and-swift

Looks like I need to filter within cellForRowAt on category at section and then pull the indexPath.row.  The issue was I had a two-d array but was always pulling what was indexPath at 0 no matter what.  That was screwing me up.

Comment: @bwor80 If you found the answer and have some working code, please include it as an answer with your code so it can help others!